# SAS: Why am I getting an 'Invalid data' error?

Tags: sas

Why do I keep getting an invalid data error? I verified the numbers are in the correct columns and that the dates are structured in 'input' just as it is in 'datalines'.

```
data ThreeDates;
input   @1  Date1 mmddyy10.
        @12 Date2 mmddyy10.
        @23 Date3 date9.;
format  Date1 
        Date2 
        Date3 mmddyy10.;

datalines;
 01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970 
 05/15/2000 05/15/2002 15May2003 
 10/10/1998 11/12/2000 25Dec2005 
 ;
 run;
```

```
NOTE: Invalid data for Date1 in line 185 1-10.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date2 in line 185 12-21.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date3 in line 185 23-31.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9-
185         01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970
Date1=. Date2=. Date3=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
NOTE: Invalid data for Date1 in line 186 1-10.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date2 in line 186 12-21.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date3 in line 186 23-31.
186         05/15/2000 05/15/2002 15May2003
Date1=. Date2=. Date3=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: Invalid data for Date1 in line 187 1-10.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date2 in line 187 12-21.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date3 in line 187 23-31.
187         10/10/1998 11/12/2000 25Dec2005
Date1=. Date2=. Date3=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=3
NOTE: The data set WORK.THREEDATES has 3 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: Is it due to the space in front of each dataline? Make sure you also put the semicolon in column 1. Also, use datalines4 always as a habit.

Comment: Ah! Fixing the spaces did the trick. What is the difference between datalines and datalines4?

Comment: I use cards4 but I am old school, SAS 5 guy. Same effect, btw. It means instead of ending the datalines with a single semi-colon, you use 4. That helps when datalines has data with a semi-colon in it. Just use it always as a habit so you dont get bit in the future.

Comment: Using a colon to specify an informat on your `input` statement will also fix the issue. e.g. `@1 date1:mmddyy10.`

Comment: @AlanC? You should have put this as an answer. First, it is good for your reputation on this site. Second, it helps people with similar problems to see this issue is actually solved and this discussion is worth wile reading. Third, it avoids others like me spend time looking for a sollution that is already there.

Comment: @Dick Horsten Considered it after it was solved. I started with a possible issue not an answer. Anyway, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it due to the space in front of each dataline? Make sure you also put the semicolon in column 1. Also, use datalines4 always as a habit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly shown in the SAS log.

```
NOTE: Invalid data for Date1 in line 185 1-10.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date2 in line 185 12-21.
NOTE: Invalid data for Date3 in line 185 23-31.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5
185         01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970
```

The RULE line with the dashes. plus sign and digits is there to help you understand exactly what was in the columns listed in the NOTE.

SAS only recognizes dates back to 1582, so trying to create dates in the year 195, 196 or 197 like on the first data line is not going to work.

You have misaligned your fixed column input with where the data is on the line.  Probably because of the extra space you have added in front of every line of data, including the line with the semicolon that marks the end of the data (and also marks the end of the data step.)

Either remove the leading spaces or adjust the cursor movement to match the actual locations.

For this data you could also just use LIST MODE input instead of FORMATTED MODE and then the number of leading spaces or number of spaces between the values wouldn't matter.   Adding the colon modifier in front of any in-line informats in the INPUT statement will insure the INPUT still operates in LIST MODE.

Note that in list mode the width specified for the informat is ignored, the whole next "word" on the line is used whatever its length.

Use a single period to indicate a missing value (numeric or character) when using LIST MODE input, The period will make sure that the values are used in the right order.

```
data ThreeDates;
  input date1 :mmddyy. date2 :mmddyy. date3 :date.;
  format date1-date3 yymmdd10.;
datalines;
     01/03/1950 01/03/1960 03Jan1970 
05/15/2000 05/15/2002          15May2003 
 10/10/1998     11/12/2000 25Dec2005 
;
proc print;
run;
```

Results

[image]

You should get in the habit of starting both the DATALINES statement and the terminal line with the semicolon in first column to avoid getting column numbers confused.